# How do I add QSerialPort Module into CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, serial-port

I want to add QSerialPort Module into CMake. From my understanding, I need to add QT += serialport into *.pro. I only want to use CMake. So I try simple CMake file to compile but it has error. The QtCore is working as  qDebug can display without any issue.

The error I am getting is:

```
undefined reference to `QSerialPort::QSerialPort(QObject*)'
undefined reference to `QSerialPort::~QSerialPort()'
undefined reference to `QSerialPort::~QSerialPort()'
```

This is the simple main.cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    QSerialPort serialPort; //this line gives error
    qDebug()<<"Hello Qt"; //this line is working as normal
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the simple CMake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(Qt5Core  COMPONENTS Qt5SerialPort REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
qt5_use_modules(untitled1 Core)
```

Comment: Command `qt5_use_modules(untitled1 Core)` link your executable with QT `Core` library, but you use `SerivalPort` library too. Use command `qt5_use_modules(untitled1 Core SerialPort)` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you @[tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev). Your suggestion solved the problem. Just for the ref for other people, I post back those working files.

The simple main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    QSerialPort serialPort;
    serialPort.setPortName("ttyACM1");
    qDebug()<<"Hello Qt";
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The simple CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
qt5_use_modules(untitled1 Core SerialPort)
```