# qtserialport with CMake in qtcreator-ros-plugin?

Tags: qt, cmake, qtserialport

I'm trying to compile qtserialport to my project in QtCreator4.9.2 with ROS plugin in.

Of course, I had follow the [doc](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Serial_Port) to install qtserialport to my Ubuntu16.04. And then, I had do some tests like this:

```
#include "QtSerialPort/qserialport.h"
#include "QtSerialPort/qserialportinfo.h"

...

Q_FOREACH(const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
    ROS_INFO("Name: %s", info.portName().toStdString().c_str());
    ROS_INFO("Description: %s", info.description().toStdString().c_str());
    ROS_INFO("Manufacturer: %s", info.manufacturer().toStdString().c_str());
    ...
}
```

But, get erros:

```
undefined reference to 'QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()'
undefined reference to 'QSerialPortInfo::portName() const'
undefined reference to 'QSerialPortInfo::description() const'
...
undefined reference to 'QSerialPortInfo::~QSerialPortInfo()'
```

You know, I'm working with CMake, so the official docs about qmake or .pro introductions is useless to me. And I had find some suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128686/how-do-i-add-qserialport-module-into-cmake), however, I'm confused with this: how to make the qtserialport as a module?

Anyway, all I want to say is that: how can I compile qtserialport with my ros CMake project? And certainly, it should also work with my QtCreator.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(xxx)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp)
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
catkin_package()

rosbuild_prepare_qt4(QtCore QtGui QtOpenGL)

file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} rsources/*.qrc)
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/xxx/*.hpp)

QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(QT_RSOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})

set(QT_SOURCES ...)
if(MSVC)
    set(...)
endif(MSVC)

add_definitions(...)
include_directories(...)
set(EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES OpenThreads osg osgDB osgViewer osgUtil osgText osgGA pthread lz4 bz2)

add_executable(... ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_MOC_HPP})
target_link_libraries(xxx ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS xxx RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

Help!

Comment: show yout CMakeLists.txt

Comment: In Qt4 there is no QtSerialPort

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator4.9.2 is your IDE's version, not the framework's version you probably are using Qt 5.1x.x version.

If you want to compile out of your IDE this line is essential

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH your/qt/path/which/can/be/obtained)
```

check this path from QT Creator > Open a Qt Project > Projects option on Left bar > Project Build Option, on CMake settings check cmake_prefix_path

```
# Before add_executable
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core SerialPort REQUIRED)

# After add_executable
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    Qt5::Core Qt5::SerialPort)
```

You also can learn package names under CMake folder of your Qt path.

```
/your/sys/path/Qt5/lib/cmake
```